# JS: Possible to iterate through nested children elements, but find the deepest element first?

Tags: javascript

**BACKGROUND**

I have a series of Objects which contain numerous nested children elements.  I need to find which of these children elements is a 'Back' button, which i've identified with a label property = '**backbtn**'.

Once I find this child, I then do a fireEvent on that which does a series of tasks for me.

Right now I'm successfully using this piece of code to iterate through my Object to find a child that has the label property of '**backbtn**'

**EDIT: EXAMPLE DATA ADDED**

```
var anotherchild = {
  name: 'Alexander',
  age: '99',
  label:'backbtn'
};
var firstchild = {
  name: 'Smith',
  age: '10',
  child: another child,
  label:'backbtn'
};
var a = {
  name: 'John',
  age: '32',
  child: first child,
  label:'backbtn'
};


function find(haystack, needle) {
  if (haystack.label === needle) {return haystack; }
  for (var i = 0; i < haystack.children.length; i ++) {
    var result = find(haystack.children[i], needle);
    if (result) { return result; }
  }
  return null;
}


find(myContent, "backbtn").fireEvent('click');
```

**THE QUESTION**

Now my issue is when I have several children that are labeled as being a 'backbtn' then the above function will simply match the first one it finds and returns that.

**I need to actually do the reverse and find the most deeply placed element first.**

Is anything like that possible?

Comment: Have you tried recursion?

Comment: _"have a series of Objects which contain numerous nested children elements. I need to find which of these children elements is a 'Back' button, which i've identified with a label property = 'backbtn'"_ Can include example of "Objects" at Question ?

Comment: You can't find a child before a parent because the only way to get to a child if by going through the parent.  So, the only way to find the deepest X is to find all X and then see which is the deepest and use that one at the end.

Comment: @guest271314 sure it goes something like this.  var a = { name:'John', age:'32', child:firstchild};   var firstchild = { name:'Smith', age:'10', child:another child, label:'backbtn'};  var anotherchild = { name:'Alexander', age:'99', child:etc, label:'backbtn'};   So when searching for 'backbtn' it should hopefully result in Alexander (with my above function it results with Smith

Comment: How do you define "deepest"? It's easy enough to search the children first before checking the parent, but that could still return a result two levels down, where later in the tree there's a match three levels down.

Comment: @torazaburo Hi.  I define "deepest" as being the most # of levels down.  So the most number of childs.  Right now it stops and returns the first child it comes across, which is actually the most superficial child, so in my example data it will return Smith, but I would want it to return Alexander first

Comment: Then another commenter is right. You have to traverse the entire tree, find all the matches, and then choose the deepest one.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `Object.hasOwnProperty()` recursively , until no match found

```js
var anotherchild = {
  name: 'Alexander',
  age: '99'
};
var firstchild = {
  name: 'Smith',
  age: '10',
  child: anotherchild
};
var a = {
  name: 'John',
  age: '32',
  child: firstchild
};

function found(obj) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(obj))
}

(function find(obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty("child")) {
    find(obj.child)
  } else {
    found(obj)
  }
}(a));
```

Comment: You're missing the check for `label` equal to `needle`.

Comment: @torazaburo _"You're missing the check for `label` equal to `needle`. "_ If interpret Question correctly , strict equality check included at existing `find` function at OP , which appear to not return expected results ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493317/js-possible-to-iterate-through-nested-children-elements-but-find-the-deepest-e/32493654#comment52846840_32493317 _"it should hopefully result in Alexander "_

Comment: @torazaburo is correct, it needs to actually check for the label = needle.  This is because there are many other objects in between that need to be ignored

Comment: @Mark _"@torazaburo is correct, it needs to actually check for the label = needle. This is because there are many other objects in between that need to be ignored"_ ? Not certain interpret comment correctly ? `js` at stacksnippets not return expected result ? See OP at _"it should hopefully result in Alexander "_ ?